# Socket.io Client repeats event action multiple times from one emit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am creating a simple diffie hellman demo with sockets and it seems that whenever my server emits any event, the client repeats it multiple times.

For example: On the client side whenever I add a message I emit this new message to the server like so.

```js
  const addMessage = (text) => {
    var newMessage = {
      id: nextID,
      from: name,
      message: text
    }
    socket.emit("send-message", newMessage);
    setNextID(nextID + 1);    
    setMessages([...messages, newMessage]);
  }
```

And then on the server side I add that message to the messages and emit the new bank of messages to the other clients.

```js
    // Send message to other person
    socket.on("send-message", (message) => {    
        messages = [...messages, message];
        console.log(messages, "Newline\n");
        
        socket.broadcast.emit("receive-message", messages);
    })
```

The clients receive it and updates their message bank. I console.log these actions.

```js
    socket.on("receive-message", (receivedMessages) => {
      console.log("receieved messages");
      setMessages(receivedMessages);
    });
```

But when I send a message it console.logs it repeats it like 100 times??
[image]

This happens for a lot of my other client side events handlers, repeating a action more than once, from just one emit from the server.

Why does this happen and how can I stop it?

Comment: Where do you put the `receive-message` listener in your app?

Comment: On the client side

Comment: Sorry for my late response ... If you are using React, be aware that if you add the listener in your components, any time the component gets updated it will add a new socket listener and for example on second second render, you'll get 2 `console.log` s. So you must add the listener in your `useEffect` hook (`componentDidMount` in class component case).

Comment: Oooh, that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `ReactJs`, be aware that if you add the listener in your components, any time the component gets updated it will add a new socket listener and for example on second second render, you'll get 2 `console.log` s. So you must add the listener in your `useEffect` hook (`componentDidMount` in class component case).

And consider that even your components can be viewed a few times so then the listener will be duplicated. So you have to close your listeners on `useEffect`'s `return` (`componentWillUnmount` in class component case)

So it must be like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive-message", (receivedMessages) => {
      console.log("receieved messages");
      setMessages(receivedMessages);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("receive-message");
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change like:

client-side:

```
socket.emit(“your event name”, “msg”)
```

server-side:

```
var io = new require(“socket-io”)()
io.on(“connection”, (socket) => {
    socket.on(“your event name”, (msg) => {
        io.emit(“your event name”, msg)
    })
})
```

try it out and it will be better :D

Comment: umm sorry, i really don’t know what version are you using in the server ( nodejs that one )

Comment: if your’re the latest version, then you need to :
var socket = io()
and also not :
socket.broadcast.emit(“name”, “msg”)
might be :
socket.emit(“name”, “msg”)
and in server-side is:
var io = new require(“socket-io”)()
io.on(“connection”, (socket) => {
    socket.on(“your msg name”, (msg) => {
       io.emit(“your msg name”, msg)
    })
})

then the broadcast flag is no need :)
and also using broadcast in somewhere isn’t good for rooms etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just send the new message

Client

```
socket.on("receive-message", (receivedMessages) => {
  console.log("receieved messages");
  setMessages(prevMessage => [...prevMessage, receivedMessages]);
});
```

Server

```
socket.on("send-message", message => {    
    messages = [...messages, message];
    console.log(messages, "Newline\n");
        
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive-message", message);
})
```